# Creating new dataframe column using string filter of other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, append

Below is the dataframe with column name 'Address'. I want to create a separate column 'City' with specific string using filter from Address column.

```
df1
Serial_No  Address 
1          India Gate Delhi
2          Delhi Redcross Hospital
3          Tolleyganj Bus Stand Kolkata
4          Kolkata Howrah
5          Katra Jammu
```

Below is the script that I am using

```
descr = []
col = 'City'
for col in df:
    if np.series(df[col]= df[df[col].str.contains('Delhi ', na=False)]:
        desc = 'Delhi'
    elif np.series(df[col]= df[df[col].str.contains('Kolkata ', na=False)]:
        desc = 'Kolkata'
    else:
        desc = 'None'
```

Below is the intended output

```
df1
Serial_No  Address                        City
1          India Gate Delhi               Delhi
2          Delhi Redcross Hospital        Delhi
3          Tolleyganj Bus Stand Kolkata   Kolkata
4          Kolkata Howrah                 Kolkata
5          Katra Jammu                    None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.DataFrame([[1,'India Gate Delhi'],[2,'Delhi Redcross Hospital'],[3,'Tolleyganj Bus Stand Kolkata'],[4,'Kolkata Howrah'],[5,'Katra Jammu']],columns=['Serial_No','Address'])
print(df1)

def f(df1):
    if 'Delhi' in df1['Address']:
        val = 'Delhi'
    elif 'Kolkata' in df1['Address']:
        val = 'Kolkata'
    else:
        val = 'None'
    return val
df1['City'] = df1.apply(f, axis=1)
print(df1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Let us try `str.extract`

```
df['new'] = df.Address.str.extract(('(Delhi|Kolkata)'))[0]
```